# How to know if the Check box is checked

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, datagridviewcheckboxcell

In a data grid view I need to loop on the rows and get the rows that contain a checked checkbox
**dgv.rows[i].cells[0].value** is returning empty in the both cases
all this is happening on the event **CellContentClick**

Comment: After I try a lot of thing I found that the problem is with the event because when I use another event the value is true. any Idea about another event that fire when I change the check of the checkbox?

Comment: You need to post some code. We've all provided valid answers based on the information you've provided. Without the relevant code, there's not much else we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'VB
Dim MyCheckBox As CheckBox = _
    CType(dgv.rows[i].cells[0].findcontrol("checkbox_id"), CheckBox)
```

C#:

```
//C#
CheckBox MyCheckBox =
    dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("checkbox_id") as CheckBox;
```

The Value property on a cell refers to text content when the cell doesn't contain any other controls.

Comment: the question is in C# code and your answers are for VB
for info you don't have to use findControl you can use ((checkbox)dgv.rows[ind].cells[0].children[0])

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox does not contain any data, the result will be a null value. You can parse the value in your loop with a `bool.Parse()` assuming the value isn't null, i.e.,

```
for ( int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    var val = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
    if ( val == null ) { continue; }

    bool isChecked = bool.Parse( val.ToString() );
}
```

Comment: Metro I already said that dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value is not working it return an empty string in both cases

Comment: @Mario - you also said `dgv.rows[ind].cells[0].children[0]` was a valid statement (refer to your comment to @mellamokb); there is no such property named `Children` on the `Cells` property. If the value is an empty string, then whatever you're using for binding is setting the value to empty. You should post all the relevant code.

Comment: please to read carefully the comment
the property children exist in the **VB code**

Answer (score 0):

```
static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> CheckedRows(this DataGridView dgv, string checkedColumnName)
    {
        return CheckedRows(dgv, dgv.Columns[checkedColumnName].Index);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> CheckedRows(this DataGridView dgv, int checkedColumnIndex)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[checkedColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            Debug.Assert(cell != null, "The column specified is not a check box column");
            if (cell != null && (bool)cell.Value)
                yield return row;
        }
    }
}
```